# C++ Appending Random Ordinal Causing Unresolved External Symbol

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, dll, unresolved-external, ordinal

I just can't figure out what **Visual C++ 2010** is doing, I've Googled the heck out of it for hours and I still have no idea what is going on. I would really, really appreciate any help I can get.

I have a DLL that I'm **importing functions** from, and I have gone through all of the usual motions. I have created a **.lib file** from the **DLL**, and I have created a header file with `extern "C"` and `__stdcall`.

Yet dispite all of my efforts the compiler *STILL* complains:

```
unresolved external symbol _Connected@4 referenced in function _main
```

Here's the **real kicker**, do you see the **ordinal** there? `@4` <-- I did not specify that anywhere in my code, VC++ just decided it liked the number 4 apparently. In the DLL the function Connected actually is listed as ordinal 11, NOT 4.

If I change the function to ordinal 4 in my .lib file **then the project compiles**, but then the DLL complains because it has Connected listed as 11.

BinDump for **NtDirect.dll:**

```
File Type: DLL

Section contains the following exports for NtDirect.dll

00000000 characteristics
4F58E306 time date stamp Thu Mar 08 09:49:10 2012
    0.00 version
       1 ordinal base
      32 number of functions
      32 number of names

ordinal hint RVA      name

      1    0 000011F0 Ask
     ...
     10    9 000016A0 ConfirmOrders
     11    A 000016E0 Connected
     12    B 00001750 Filled
     ...
     32   1F 00002070 UnsubscribeMarketData

Summary

   13000 .data
    3000 .rdata
    2000 .reloc
    1000 .rsrc
    F000 .text
```

Code for **main.cpp:**

```
#include <iostream>
#include "ninja.h"

int main()
{
    std::cout << Connected(1);
    std::cin.get();

    return 0;
}
```

Declaration in **ninja.h**: (only showing connected to conserve space)

```
extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) int __stdcall Connected(int showMessage);
```

Export in **NtDirect.def**: (I've tried this with AND without specifying ordinals.)

```
LIBRARY NtDirect

EXPORTS
...
ConfirmOrders@10
Connected@11
Filled@12
...
```

**Already Tried:**

Building .lib from both a .def file containing `Connected@11` AND `Connected`. I've also tried using other functions than just Connected, they also don't work. I've tried playing around with my import declaration (adding and removing `extern "C"`).

I have also made sure that the DLL is in the same folder as my executable, and I have added NtDirect.dll to the linker so it is accessible.

**I am running Windows 7 64-bit.**

Comment: The @4 is not an ordinal, it is the [`__stdcall` name decoration](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zxk0tw93(v=vs.110).aspx) used by Visual C++.

Comment: Really? That's so odd since @ is used to define ordinals in the .def file. Wow ok.

Comment: Ok so thanks to your comment I was able to learn more about how things are named and how the various calling conventions work. I can't believe I spent HOURS looking around the web and pulling out my hair over this. My question feels so dumb now. -_- Maybe a future me will see this though at least ...

Comment: what was the ending solution to this? I am having the same issues